# Why can't I override the default validation error message?

Tags: php, zend-framework, validation

I'm using [`Zend_Validate`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.html) to validate some form input (Zend Framework version is 1.8.2). For some reason, using the [`Zend_Filter_Input`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.filter.input.html) interface as described [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.filter.input.html) does not work:

```
$data = $_POST;
$filters = array('*' => array('StringTrim'));
$validators = array('driverName' => array('NotEmpty','messages' => 'This should override the default message but does not!'));
$inputFilter = new Zend_Filter_Input($filters,$validators,$data);
$messages = $inputFilter->getMessages();
debug($messages); //show me the variable contents
```

Output from `debug($messages)`:

```
Array
(
    [driverName] => Array
        (
            [isEmpty] => You must give a non-empty value for field 'driverName'
        )

)
```

No matter what I do, I cannot override that message. If I use the validator directly, i.e.:

```
$notEmpty = new Zend_Validate_NotEmpty();      
$notEmpty->setMessage('This WILL override the default validation error message');
if (!$notEmpty->isValid($_POST['driverName'])) {
    $messages = $notEmpty->getMessages();
    debug($messages);
}
```

Output from `debug($messages)`:

```
Array
(
    [isEmpty] => Please enter your name
)
```

Bottom line. I can get validators to work, but without the benefits of the `Zend_Filter_Input` interface method of validation I might as well write my own validation class!

Does anyone have a clue as to why this is happening, and how to fix it?

Could it be a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `messages` key in the validator array must be passed an array of key/value pairs, where the key is the validation message constant, and the value is your custom error message. Here's an example:

```
    $validators = array(

        'excerpt' => array(
            'allowEmpty' => true,
            array('StringLength', 0, Ctrl::getOption('blog/excerpt/length')), 
            'messages' => array(Zend_Validate_StringLength::TOO_LONG => 'The post excerpt must not exceed '.Ctrl::getOption('blog/excerpt/length').' characters.')
        ),

    );
```

However, in your case, the error message you are receiving is coming from the the `allowEmpty` meta command of Zend_Filter_Input. This isn't really a standard validator. You can set it like so:

```
$options = array(
    'notEmptyMessage' => "A non-empty value is required for field '%field%'"
);

$input = new Zend_Filter_Input($filters, $validators, $data, $options);

// alternative method:

$input = new Zend_Filter_Input($filters, $validators, $data);
$input->setOptions($options);
```

If you need a different not empty message per field, I'd recommend setting `allowEmpty => true` and adding a `NotEmpty` validator with a custom message.

For your reference, the correct message key for the `NotEmpty` validator is `Zend_Validate_NotEmpty::IS_EMPTY`

Comment: @Jason - Thank you for the details & correct answer. The $options parameter nailed it. Perfect, thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

The MESSAGES argument takes an array, not a string. Try this:

```
$validators = array('driverName' => 
                     array('NotEmpty',
                           'messages' => array(
                                0 => 'This should override the default message but does not!'
                            )
                     )
              );
```

Comment: @Steve - I had already tried that, the manual would have you believe that it works, when in fact it does not, but thanks for the answer nontheless :)

Comment: @Karim - That's too bad - it used to work this way in ZF 1.0, as well as accepting validation constants as keys in the message override array. I liked how ZF provided an index based shortcut, but I guess they really want to make everything explicit/convention based.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug, it's in the JIRA of Zend Framework...